# Using RestSharp Api with GustPay

Tags: c#, asp.net, restsharp

I am trying to use RestSharp Api to use GustPay Api. I am confused how to pass “api_key” and “api_secret” in request.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.gustpay.com/api/gust_pass_venue_assignment");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
                              {
                                  RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
                              };

            request.AddBody(request.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
            {
                venue_name = "Cape Town Stadium",
                latitude = "-33.903441",
                longitude = "18.41113"
            }));


            var response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `request.AddParameter(...)`. Call it once for each of your three parameters: api_key, api_secret, and data.

Edited to add: RestSharp will add these parameters to the body of the request because it's a POST request. It would add them to the querystring instead if it were a GET requests, but that's not the case in your example.